# How to create a new file / an empty file using command or shortcut or without command?

Tags: command-line, files, filesystem, directory, shortcuts

How to create a new file / an empty file using command or shortcut or without command?

Like To create new Folder,

```
shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + N
Right click and create New Folder
```

Comment: `touch` will create a file, but what do you mean without command?

Comment: @guiverc Like To create new Folder, we can use shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + N or Right click and create New Folder without any commands.

Comment: you can create an empty file with a redirect output `> empty.txt` dont see an advantage using shortcut for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using touch filename.fileextention

   ```
   touch filename.fileextention
    For ex. - touch test.txt
   ```
2. Using >filename.fileextention

   ```
   >filename.fileextention
   For ex. - >test.txt
   ```
3. create any fileextention template in Home/Templates and you can
   access that template to create file. For ex. create test.txt file in
   Home/Templates folder. Now wherever you wants to create an .txt
   extention file you can simply create using `right click-> New Document- -> test`

Answer (score 3):

There is the "Templates" mechanism, which still works but is kind of hidden nowadays.

In your home directory, create a "Templates" folder. In that folder, you can place for example an empty file called "Plain Text.txt".

Once this directory exists and contains at least a file, you will have a right-click menu item "New Document" when you right-click an empty space in the folder. You can select your "Plain Text" menu entry, and that will create a copy of the empty "Plain Text.txt" in your current folder.

You can place different template files there, e.g. another one with an empty Writer file, letter templates, etc.

In standard Ubuntu, no Templates folder is created by default. Then, Files does not provide a right-click menu item. That makes it difficult to discover this feature, which exists for a long time.